# Error 404 con archivos JSON en IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Quiero configurar la traducción de lenguaje de `Datatable` por medio de url local en una solución de ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
tblJs = tblHtml.DataTable({
                destroy: true,
                searching: false,
                ajax: { url: '/Area/Control/getDatos'},
                "language": { "url": "~/Scripts/Utilities/datatables/Spanish.json" },
            });
```

La dirección del archivo es correcto, pero al consultarlo me muestra esta pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Que configuración me hace falta para cargar el json con la traducción?

Comment: La notación con el símbolo  `~` en la url no funciona en cliente. Deberías poner la url completa del archivo json: `languaje: { url: "http://tuservidor/Scri...`

Comment: Me sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje de error 404.3

Comment: Puedes copiar la ruta absoluta y pegar en tu explorador para verificar que te traiga datos.

Comment: Perdona, no me había fijado en el mensaje. Prueba a poner la url directamente en el navegador. Si sigues obteniendo el mismo error es un problema de configuración del servidor. Deberás configurar el tipo MIME para la extensión json.

Comment: @AaronRomero recuerda revisar [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

> Debido a que el OP no comprende la temática del sitio, puso su solución (respuesta) en la pregunta. [**Revisiones**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/129296/revisions)

---

**Solución:**

> En el archivo **web.config** agregue la **configuración MIME** 
>   [Referencia](https://edeortuzar.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/404-con-archivos-json-en-iis/)

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Contribución de [Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva)

Comment: A tener en cuenta... esto funcionará en server con IIS 7.0 o superior que soporte el elemento [mimeMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) en StaticContent [Mas info aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)